# SPARK: dropDuplicates in every partitions only

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want to `dropDuplicates` in every partitions, not the full DataFrame.

Is that possible with PySpark? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
withNoDuplicates = df.withColumn("partitionID", f.spark_partition_id()).dropDuplicates()
```

Basically you add a column of the partition id using spark_partition_id and then do the distinct, it will consider different partitions separately

Comment: After dropDuplicates in every partition, Does spark shuffle and re-dropDuplicates again to remove possible duplicate items in different partitions?

Comment: @KevinLeo I am not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Let's say 'df' has 30 partitions. After adding partitionID column and dropDuplicate in every partition, we get 30 result sets.  Will spark shuffle the 30 result sets and check for duplicate items again?

Comment: If I understand correctly then the answer is yes. You can see this by doing .explain(true) on the resulting dataframe. You will see it ends with a HashAggregate. This would basically repartition the entire data as needed

Comment: Will this improve the performance over calling `dropDuplicates` on two different columns?

Comment: @AssafMendelson, thank you for your perfect answer. Would you please tell me, if Spark uses **Shuffle** with your command of dropping duplicates?

Comment: @M_Gh I think not, it should be smart enough, however, you can just do explain and verify.